# Vauxhall Vectra cdti 150 turbo whine

Tags: noise, vauxhall

I have a faint whine from the turbo, most evident when the engine is cold. (Barely audible when warm). No loss in power at all and the noise cannot be heard when the engine is under pressure (ie more boost). It can only be heard at approx 1/4 throttle in 1st,2nd and 3rd gears, cannot really hear it after that.

Its a 2009 Vectra SRI 150, has 81k miles up, serviced 2k miles ago when I got it.

It sounds like a faint police siren, it whines up as the turbo kicks in and tails off when I change gear but as I said, only while not pushing it hard.

If I open the bonnet It cannot be heard at idle but if I rev up to approx 1800-2000 rpm it can be heard. Doesnt appear to be any leaks in the exhaust system and the noise is coming from somewhere near the turbo.

Any ideas of things to check? Is it something to worry about or are these engines known for being a little noisy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that you aren't getting enough oil to the turbo, which means that it's running dry. Which is very bad for something that spins at 160 000 RPM. It may also be that you have significant carbon buildup in the turbo, which will make it fail pretty soon. OR it could be something less serious. But as I found out the expensive way: get that thing checked out by an expert. If you live in the UK, I'd suggest finding out if Courtenay Motorsport is close enough to you. They are by FAR the best Vauxhall shop in the country and they won't BS you.